# OneToMany relationship in springdata jpa with a foreign key which is also part of Composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring hibernate framework and working on a car tracking application with two classes Vehicle and Vehicle reading class. There is One-to-Many relationship from the vehicle side and Many-to-one vehicle from the Vehicle Reading class.

The primary key in vehicle class is "vin" column and which is foreign key in the vehicleReadings class.

The primary key in vehicleReadings class is ReadingId which is a composite key with vehicle_id and timestamp.

The code for the vehicle class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Vehicles")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "vin")
    private String vin;

    @Column(name = "make")
    private String make;
    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;
    @Column(name = "year")
    private Integer year;

    @Column(name = "redlineRpm")
    private Integer redlineRpm;
    @Column(name = "maxFuelVolume")
    private Integer maxFuelVolume;
    @Column(name = "lastServiceDate")
    private String lastServiceDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vehicle")
    Set<VehicleReadings> vehicleReadings;
}
```

The code for the Vehicle Readings class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Readings")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VehicleReadings {
        @EmbeddedId
        private ReadingId readingId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name ="vin", referencedColumnName = "vin")
        @MapsId("vehicleId")
        private Vehicle vehicle;

        @Column(name= "latitude")
        private Float latitude;

        @Column(name = "longitude")
        private Float longitude;

        @Column(name = "fuelvolume")
        private Float fuelVolume;

        @Column(name = "checkenginelighton")
        private Boolean checkEngineLightOn;

        @Column(name = "enginecoolantlow")
        private Boolean engineCoolantLow;

        @Column(name = "enginerpm")
        private Integer engineRpm;


}
```

The code for readingsId class

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class ReadingId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "vin")
    String vehicleId;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    String timestamp;
}
```

When a REST request for the readings table is received the following error occurs:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [io.egen.car_tracker_application.domain.VehicleReadings.vehicle]
    at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:509) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:704) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE
```

Could someone guide me how to correctly set up the relationship between the entities ?

**Edit:**

Sample Readings table input through REST input:

```
{
   "vin": "1HGCR2F3XFA027534",
   "latitude": 41.803194,
   "longitude": -88.144406,
   "timestamp": "2017-05-25T17:31:25.268Z",
   "fuelVolume": 1.5,
   "speed": 85,
   "engineHp": 240,
   "checkEngineLightOn": false,
   "engineCoolantLow": true,
   "cruiseControlOn": true,
   "engineRpm": 6300
}
```

Comment: there is data available for vehicle inside vehicle readings table correct? can you tell me how you are actually reading the VehicleReadings entity?

Comment: @Guardian The reading is received through REST endpoint and have sample request in the Edit section.